# Defining ENUM in the Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, enums

I'm trying to define an enum class in Yii following this example:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/enum/

It all makes sense but I'm not sure where to put the file with the class declaration. I'm trying to connect it with a simple 'gender' field from my database so I put the definition in a 'Gender.php' file.

I've tried placing it in folder 'Gender' under extensions or moving the file directly into the 'components' folder but no success so far. I keep getting an error that it failed to open file stream for 'Gender.php' when trying to include it - this happening, for example, when I try to populate a drop down list:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'gender', Gender::getDataForDropDown());
```

Comment: did you try like this http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/16056-extension-enum?

Comment: I did try extensions/enum/Gender.php as well and I still get the same error..